# Can a lambda instantiate a template function?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, template-specialization, c++-experimental

Questions regarding the use of C++14 generic lambdas or C++20 template lambdas are typically about generating lambdas with the appropriate parameterized types.

*My question is*, is it possible for a lambda parameter, or its evaluation, to force the instantiation (or *specialization*) of a template, e.g., a template function? The parameter `(n)` would need to be qualified as `constexpr` for this to work.

```
template <int n> ret_type fn (...) {...}
...
auto fx = [] (int n) { return fn<n>(...) }
```

I'm not completely up to date with C++20, or newer working proposals, and admit there are still nuances with `constexpr`, etc., in C++17 lambdas and other edge features, that have me looking up `cppreference`, Josuttis, and others pretty frequently.

I know this close to an XY-problem. Since template instantiation is performed at compile time, a lambda expression for a template parameter seems like an anti-pattern. But since templates *can* be instantiated if types and constant values are known at compile time, are there any proposals to allow such a mechanism?

Comment: function parameters cannot be `constexpr` so your concrete example won't work. But I suppose that is besides the question you're asking?

Comment: @rubenvb - yes. AFAIK there's no `concept` / `requires` syntax like some `(constexpr int n)` - I don't see a standard solution, but I'm curious about language proposals the like. Lambdas get more features with every standard since their introduction, for example.

Comment: @BrettHale you mean like [`consteval`?](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval)

Comment: @Mgetz - In a sense. If the template specialization parameter is a `consteval` expression. My question is starting to feel more and more impractical as I think about it - given the constraints such a hypothetical 'lambda' would required...

Comment: @BrettHale I think you're probably asking the wrong question. I'd suggest asking about what you're trying to do instead of the potential solution. There are possibilities here (I've done crazy things with `std::integer_sequence`) but without knowing what you're trying to do it's hard to give a good answer.

Comment: @Mgetz - I already stated that this borders on an XY problem. But that's a question specific to an application - not a question about the language, or any future proposals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is technically *yes*, lambda bodies can instantiate template functions.  The actual example doesn't work, because `int n` as a parameter can't be used that way.

There is an easy workaround

```
template<auto x>
using constant_t = std::integral_constant< std::decay_t<decltype(x)>, x >;
template<auto x>
constexpr constant_t<x> constant = {};

template <int n> int fn () { int arr[n] = {0}; return sizeof(arr); }
auto fx = [] (auto n) { return fn<n>(); };
std::cout << fx( constant<3> );
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/W4vMvchs6).

Here I made the `constant<x>` variable template that creates an instance of `std::integral_constant<X, x>`.  This is a stateless (but not valueless!) type that has a constexpr conversion to its value.

We can pass that to a lambda, and so long as the lambda takes it by value we can then convert it to a `constexpr` value within the lambda, including passing it as a template non-type parameter, instantiating a template function specialization as you are asking for.

The can be done without the `constant` variable template, ie if you don't have `auto` parameter support:

```
template<std::size_t N>
using index_t = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>;
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr index_t<N> index = {};
```

we can use a type-specific version of it, and just pass that, and it works the same way.

---

Aside, `constant<?>` is fun.  For example:

```
using upFILE=std::unique_ptr<
  std::FILE,
  constant_t<std::fclose>
>;

upFILE file( fopen("hello.txt", "r") );
```

does the right thing<sup>tm</sup>.

Comment: So that's how you'd do it without abusing `std::integer_sequence` nice...

Comment: This is quite elegant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question as asked is: yes, a lambda's body can instantiate templates.

The concrete example in your question is not possible, as function parameters cannot be `constexpr`, which is necessary for something to be used as a template parameter.

You can use constexpr variables that are accessible from the lambda's definition's scope:

```
template<int N>
void something();

constexpr int N = 10;

int main()
{
    auto f = [] { something<N>(); };
    f();
}
```

Live example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/rqnhYaK8W), in which `something` is instantiated inside de lambda expression's body. But I don't think that is what you are after. Note that calling the lambda object does not result (and could never result) in the instantiation of a template.

Comment: Point of contention: you can sort of do it by abusing parameter packs and `std::integer_sequence`. Not that I'd recommend it.

Comment: The value you'd be passing to the template will still be something (indirectly) `constexpr` and could never ever come from e.g. user input. That is in my eyes no different than using e.g. T::value_type where T is used as the type of a parameter of a function template.

Comment: not disagreeing but I don't recall the OP saying they needed that flexibility.